# Send request to API to receive JSON and append it to the document as raw JSON text

Tags: javascript, json, request

I am trying to fetch the data from `randomuser.me/api/` and use the **insertAdjacentText** method to append it to my blank document. So how do I receive data and insert it as adjacent HTML?

```
fetch('https://www.randomuser.me/api/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => document.body.insertAdjacentText('afterend', Promise.resolve(data).then(function() { return data; })))
```

Comment: There is currently no real question here. “I am trying” is not one. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to include an actual question and / or problem description.

Comment: And where is the code that you have tried?
What error are you getting?

Comment: Question seems to be framed incorrectly , Need an edit. Seems like the issue in fetching the resultset from promise object. Current code is just printing promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are not able to fetch the api result from the promise correctly. Wondering below might help.

```
var d = fetch('https://www.randomuser.me/api/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.results[0]));
    document.body.insertAdjacentText("afterend",JSON.stringify(data.results[0]));
  });
 //
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I wanted. So I absolutely forgot to stringify the json information I received...